# Actualizar el estado de tu proyecto en github mediante git

Tags: git, github

No tengo claro si estoy entendiendo el manejo de `git` (combinado con un repositorio como puede ser github).

Supongamos que ya he creado mi proyecto y he hecho los pasos iniciales de `git` y ya está todo en mi repositorio de github. Yo sigo trabajando y modifico mi archivo `main.py` (inicialmente estaba vacío y ahora ya he empezado a codificar) y por hoy ya he terminado.

En este punto entiendo es interesante actualizar el estado de mi proyecto, entonces según he entendido ahora debería hacer un `git commit -m "Comentarios"`, esto lo que hace es actualizar mi repositorio local y a continuación un `git push -u origin main`.

¿Es esto correcto?

Siguiendo mis pasos, hago un `commit` y me aparece el siguiente mensaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debo hacer un `add`, si la respuesta es que sí, alguien puede ayudarme a entenderlo? Yo entendía que el add era para añadir nuevos elementos, pero si se trata de actualizar los que ya se tenían no hace falta.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: `según he entendido ahora debería hacer un git commit -m "Comentarios", esto lo que hace es actualizar mi repositorio local`. No. Eso lo que hace es crear una nueva revisión en tu repositorio **local**. No actualiza nada.... no hace operaciones contra el repositorio remoto (o sea, `origin`, como indicas en el comando posterior). El push lo que hace es _empujar_ la rama main (que asumios ahí estás trabajando) en el repositorio remoto.

Comment: Entiendo, entonces me podrías un ejemplo de los pasos que debería seguir por favor? @eftshift0

Comment: La respuesta de Camilo es apropiada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si, tienes que hacer un add. En corto, git hace el *commit* de todo lo que encuentre en el *staging area*. Entonces, antes de hacer un *commit*, tienes que decirle pasar tus archivos a ese *staging area*. Esto lo haces con un add. Si usas el comando `git add .`, incluyes todos los archivos que has cambiado. También puedes elegirlos usando `git add *direccion del archivo*`.